# Rails - How to test if a form method is post or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm doing an integration test using mini test and cant figure out how to test if the displayed forms method is post or patch. This is the best I could come up with but doesn't work

```
  assert_select 'form method', 'post'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using capybara for your integration-tests, you could do the following:

```
has_selector?("form[method='POST']") # => it's a POST
has_selector?("form[method='PATCH']") # => it's a PATCH
```

Comment: Nope not using capybara. Doing the tests without any test addon gems

Comment: Just ended up getting and using capybara

Answer (score -1):

Open the firebug on your browser click on the "net" tab and submit the form, you will see the post call in the network tab and in the same call you can check the method or type.